# How to execute goose command with quotes via exec.Command

Tags: go

It isn't working:

```
func runMigrations(port int, pathToMigrate string) error {
    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        cmd = exec.Command("cmd", "/C", fmt.Sprintf("goose postgres \"user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres host=localhost port=%d sslmode=disable\" up", port))
    } else {
        cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("goose postgres \"user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres host=localhost port=%d sslmode=disable\" up", port) )
    }

    cmd.Dir = pathToMigrate

    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s", output)
    }

    return nil
}

error: "goose run: "password=postgres": no such command"
```

I'm sure the problem is that there are quotes in the command, causing it to not work correctly. How can I fix this?
I'm talking about behaviour on Windows. I don't know if this will work on Linux.

Comment: Why are you adding extra quotes in the first place? I don’t know what the requirements for `goose` arguments are, but it would probably be easier to call it directly without the shell involved.